# Derivative of a function containing indicator function?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Consider $\delta\in \mathbb{R}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a map defined as
$$
f(X; \delta):=\delta*1\{X\geq 0\}+X
$$
where $1\{X\geq 0\}$ is $1$ if $X \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise, and $\delta$ is a parameter.

Can I compute the derivative of $f(X)$ with respect to $X$? Can you specify where it is well defined and how can I deal with the indicator function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a classical sense $f$ is not differentiable w.r.t. $x$ at $x = 0$ unless $\delta = 0$ since the function is discontinuous at $0$ (hence non-differentiable). I guess that neither does the weak derivative exist according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849353/weak-derivative-heaviside-function), but if you are interested in integrating w.r.t. $\mathrm f$ then it can be easily done since it has finite variation, and the "derivative" at the jump point can be easily interpreted:
$$
  \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\mathrm df(x) = \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\mathrm dx + \delta g(0)
$$
for all nice $g$ (e.g. continuous).