# Dominated Convergence Theorem for Weak Derivative of Heaviside Function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

My question primarily stems from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849353/weak-derivative-heaviside-function) and Bressan's "Lecture Notes on Functional Analysis (With Applications to Linear Partial Differential Equations)".

In it, to prove that the weak derivative of Heaviside function does not exist, they used Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to show that for some $g\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$, $$
\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{-\delta}^\delta |g(x)|\,dx = 0
$$

I am not perplexed about how to use DCT, but rather why. Isn't this fact obvious for any function since the integral will be over a region of zero measure in the limit (i.e. $\int_a^a f(x)\,dx=0$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$)? Why do we need to invoke DCT to show this fact? I'm not sure what did I miss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are more immediate proofs than invoking Dominated Convergence, and maybe you're intuiting some such thing in saying "it's obvious". But, still, if a thing is obvious, it should be possible to explain it persuasively...

For this example, I'd convince myself of the truth of the conclusion that $\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{-\delta}^\delta |g(x)|\;dx=0$ for every locally absolutely integrable $g$, as follows: by countable-disjoint additivity,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{{1\over n+1}}^{1\over n} |g(x)|\;dx
\;=\; \int_0^1 |g(x)|\;dx \;<\; \infty
$$
Thus, the infinite sum of integrals converges, so the infinite tails $\int_0^{1/n}$ must go to $0$.